# UILongPressGestureRecognizer does not generate continuous events

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

Apple Doc says,Long-press gestures are continuous.However,when I add long press gesture to my view and log event to my console,it does not produce continuous event when I put my finger to the view(just 2 or 3 logs).Here is the code.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let gesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "longPress:")
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)

}

func longPress(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer!) {

    println("button Longpressed")
}
```

Can someone tell me where I did wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you expect it to be continuous? It reports that you pressed for a long time. If you don't also drag, that's the end of the story.

Comment: I want to implement zooming slider just like built-in camera's slider.So when I long press my "+" button, the slider's thumb image moves smoothly.

Comment: Well, that's not what a long press gesture recognizer does. It doesn't report "the user is still holding his finger down". It reports that the user has pressed for a long time - once. Why not just use a button? You can get an event for touch down inside and touch up inside, so you know when the touch starts and when it ends and you can be sliding in between.

Comment: But how could I make UISlider's thumb moves smoothly when touch down event happens, I don't know how to produce continuous event using that event.

Comment: You could use a timer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to use `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` like using `touchesBegan`, `touchesMove`, `touchesEnd` method? You may try to set the `minimumPressDuration` of `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to 0 and figure out whether it supply your requirement.

Comment: Sorry, that is not what I want.谢谢。